# I think my Go server is killing my Mongo servers

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

So long story short, I have many servers across 3 AWS regions.  In an effort to reduce servers, which are written in Node, I've rewritten them in Go.  To my delight and surprise 1 Go server can handle what 10 Node servers handle with lower CPU utilization and less ELB latency.  This is AWESOME lol.  However, I think maybe that they are too fast lol.  We have a single (yes I know very bad) MongoDB server used to log data.  Every request that comes in is logged in a particular way and sent to this server. Since adding just 2 Go servers that MongoDB server has started to crash.

**TRACEBACK**

```
2016-11-09T03:06:41.240-0500 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] warning couldn't write to / rename file /data/data/db/journal/prealloc.2: Couldn't open directory '/data/data/db/journal' for flushing: errno:24 Too many open files
2016-11-09T03:06:41.240-0500 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] warning exception opening journal file couldn't open file /data/data/db/journal/j._213 for writing errno:9 Bad file descriptor
2016-11-09T03:06:41.240-0500 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] error exception in dur::journal couldn't open file /data/data/db/journal/j._213 for writing errno:9 Bad file descriptor
2016-11-09T03:06:41.242-0500 F JOURNAL  [journal writer] dbexception in journalWriterThread causing immediate shutdown: 13516 couldn't open file /data/data/db/journal/j._213 for writing errno:9 Bad file descriptor
2016-11-09T03:06:41.242-0500 I -        [journal writer] Invariant failure false src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/dur_journal_writer.cpp 258
2016-11-09T03:06:41.246-0500 I JOURNAL  [durability] warning couldn't write to / rename file /data/data/db/journal/prealloc.2: couldn't open file /data/data/db/journal/prealloc.2 for writing errno:9 Bad file descriptor
2016-11-09T03:06:41.246-0500 F JOURNAL  [durability] dbexception in durThread causing immediate shutdown: 13516 couldn't open file /data/data/db/journal/j._213 for writing errno:9 Bad file descriptor
2016-11-09T03:06:41.246-0500 I -        [durability] Invariant failure false src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/dur.cpp 862
2016-11-09T03:06:41.246-0500 I CONTROL  [journal writer]
 0xf51949 0xef1671 0xed6192 0xd17613 0xf9f9b4 0x7fd09697d184 0x7fd09544337d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"B51949"},{"b":"400000","o":"AF1671"},{"b":"400000","o":"AD6192"},{"b":"400000","o":"917613"},{"b":"400000","o":"B9F9B4"},{"b":"7FD096975000","o":"8184"},{"b":"7FD095349000","o":"FA37D"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.0.3", "gitVersion" : "b40106b36eecd1b4407eb1ad1af6bc60593c6105", "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.13.0-54-generic", "version" : "#91-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 26 19:15:08 UTC 2015", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "F56F80CB96B4DBFC070BEB0ADAC7D6B274BFC6B1" }, { "b" : "7FFF14FD0000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1C0D0A18FF043EED9EE11DB5E5E90A3F74729341" }, { "b" : "7FD096975000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "31E9F21AE8C10396171F1E13DA15780986FA696C" }, { "b" : "7FD096716000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "74864DB9D5F69D39A67E4755012FB6573C469B3D" }, { "b" : "7FD09633A000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AAE7CFF8351B730830BDBCE0DCABBE06574B7144" }, { "b" : "7FD096132000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E2A6DD5048A0A051FD61043BDB69D8CC68192AB7" }, { "b" : "7FD095F2E000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DA9B8C234D0FE9FD8CAAC8970A7EC1B6C8F6623F" }, { "b" : "7FD095C2A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "76190E922AF7457D078F75C9B15FA184E83EB506" }, { "b" : "7FD095924000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D144258E614900B255A31F3FD2283A878670D5BC" }, { "b" : "7FD09570E000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "36311B4457710AE5578C4BF00791DED7359DBB92" }, { "b" : "7FD095349000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CF699A15CAAE64F50311FC4655B86DC39A479789" }, { "b" : "7FD096B93000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D0F537904076D73F29E4A37341F8A449E2EF6CD0" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x29) [0xf51949]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0xE1) [0xef1671]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15invariantFailedEPKcS1_j+0xB2) [0xed6192]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur13JournalWriter20_journalWriterThreadEv+0x953) [0xd17613]
 mongod(+0xB9F9B4) [0xf9f9b4]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x8184) [0x7fd09697d184]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7fd09544337d]
```

In an efforts to fix this I increased the ulimit on that machine. However I think something can also be done from the programmic side.

**Here is my mongo package**

```
package mongo

import (
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

var (
    // TagDB ...
    TagDB DataStore
    // LogDB ...
    LogDB DataStore
)

func init() {
    TagDB.ConnectToTagserver()
    LogDB.ConnectToLogServer()
}

// DataStore containing a pointer to a mgo session
type DataStore struct {
    Session *mgo.Session
}

// ConnectToTagserver is a helper method that connections to pubgears' tagserver
// database
func (ds *DataStore) ConnectToTagserver() {
    mongoDBDialInfo := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{"some_IP"},
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
        Database: "tagserver",
    }
    sess, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoDBDialInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    sess.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
    TagDB.Session = sess
}


// database SERVER IN QUESTION
func (ds *DataStore) ConnectToLogServer() {
    mongoDBDialInfo := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{"some_IP"}, 
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
        Database: "nginx_logs",
    }
    sess, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoDBDialInfo)
    if err != nil {
        println(1)
        panic(err)
    }
    sess.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
    LogDB.Session = sess
}

// Close is a helper method that ensures the session is properly terminated
func (ds *DataStore) Close() {
    ds.Session.Close()
}
```

**Here is the file that used that package**

```
package models

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"

    "./mongo"
)

// RawRequests ...
type RawRequests struct {
    TagServer   string            `json:"tag_server"`
    Server      string            `json:"server"`
    Slug        string            `json:"slug"`
    Zone        string            `json:"zone"`
    Size        string            `json:"size"`
    Network     string            `json:"network"`
    TagHash     string            `json:"tag_hash"`
    Extra       string            `json:"extra"`
    Logged      time.Time         `json:"logged"`
    Date        string            `json:"date"`
    Hour        int               `json:"hour"`
    QueryParams map[string]string `json:"query_params"`
}

// RawTagRequests ...
type RawTagRequests struct {
    TagServer   string            `json:"tag_server"`
    Server      string            `json:"server"`
    Slug        string            `json:"slug"`
    Zone        string            `json:"zone"`
    Size        string            `json:"size"`
    Network     string            `json:"network"`
    TagHash     string            `json:"tag_hash"`
    Extra       string            `json:"extra"`
    Logged      time.Time         `json:"logged"`
    Date        string            `json:"date"`
    Hour        int               `json:"hour"`
    QueryParams map[string]string `json:"query_params"`
    ChainNext   string            `json:"chain_next"`
}

// LogRequest ...
func LogRequest(tagServer string, server string, slug string, zone string, size string, network string, extra string, tagHash string, queryParams map[string]string) error {
    dbsession := mongo.LogDB.Session.Copy()
    defer dbsession.Close()
    logCollection := dbsession.DB("nginx_logs").C("raw_requests")
    d := time.Now()
    hour, _, _ := d.Clock()
    year, month, day, _ := formatDate(d.Year(), int(d.Month()), d.Day())
    date := fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s-%s", year, month, day)
    return logCollection.Insert(bson.M{"tag_server": tagServer, "server": server, "slug": slug, "zone": zone, "size": size, "network": network, "tag_hash": tagHash, "extra": extra, "logged": time.Now(), "date": date, "hour": hour, "query_params": queryParams})
}

// LogTagRequests ...
func LogTagRequests(tagServer string, server string, slug string, zone string, size string, network string, extra string, tagHash string, queryParams map[string]string, chainHash string) error {
    dbsession := mongo.LogDB.Session.Copy()
    defer dbsession.Close()
    logCollection := dbsession.DB("nginx_logs").C("raw_tag_requests")
    d := time.Now()
    hour, _, _ := d.Clock()
    year, month, day, _ := formatDate(d.Year(), int(d.Month()), d.Day())
    date := fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s-%s", year, month, day)
    return logCollection.Insert(bson.M{"tag_server": tagServer, "server": server, "slug": slug, "zone": zone, "size": size, "network": network, "tag_hash": tagHash, "extra": extra, "logged": time.Now(), "date": date, "hour": hour, "query_params": queryParams, "chain_hash": chainHash})
}

func formatDate(year int, month int, day int) (y string, m string, d string, err error) {
    var tmonth, tday, tyear string
    tyear = strconv.Itoa(year)
    // convert the month and year and replace with the correct number of digits
    if month < 10 {
        tmonth = "0" + strconv.Itoa(int(month))
    } else {
        tmonth = strconv.Itoa(int(month))
    }
    if day < 10 {
        tday = "0" + strconv.Itoa(int(day))
    } else {
        tday = strconv.Itoa(int(day))
    }
    if len(tmonth) == 2 && len(tday) == 2 && len(tyear) == 4 {
        return tyear, tmonth, tday, nil
    }
    return tyear, tmonth, tday, errors.New("One of the values passed in does not meet the time format requirement month-day-year --> 1991-01-15")
}
```

Lastly within my route, I simply call my method `go LogRequest(tagServer, host, site, channel, adSize, network, tagExtra, tagHash, queryParams)`

Comment: I suggest you reuse your sessions instead of calling copy/close on them to reduce the number of open sockets. This is likely the cause of "too many open files". I read on the docs that a session is thread-safe.

Comment: I thought that by copying them I was reusing them.  Can you provide a small example? @squiguy

Comment: Is this the different between Clone and Copy? Your comment guided my search queries and that's what i stumbled on.

Comment: I haven't used MongoDB myself, but I personally would just share my session and avoid using clone or copy. This is what I have been reading: https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session

Comment: I am using a session. It's part of my DataStore struct. But to use the session it has to be cloned or copied per request otherwise it returns the error session closed. I'm even using the Monotonic mode as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use copy only once per request-response cycle. Using it in each call to models will result in consuming a lot of sockets. Each model call is opening a socket and closing it(using defer) while exiting the routine. Try to reuse a copied session across multiple calls to your db in the same request-response cycle.
2. From the logs and the code snippet, it looks like that you should take care of 1 until unless in each request-response cycle you are calling your model routines to perform CRUD only once.
3. Copy uses a new socket to open connection preserving the auth credentials from the parent session while clone uses the same socket as the parent session(while using the cloned session one of the parent/child will have to wait on the socket until the other one is done with it). Hence, to process multiple requests to your server in parallel its better to use copy per request handler.(https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.Clone)
4. After increasing the ulimit on a machine do make sure it gets reflected immediately - http://lzone.de/blog/Apply-changes-to-limits.conf-immediately.

Comment: So I've modded my code.  I instantiate a session object at the top of each requests and passed a clone of the session into the method for use.  I didn't copy the session because i'm spinning these off as go routines and the mongo call is an insert so I don't need to wait for any return data.  Thank you for advice :-)